# How to pass float in pygame.draw.circle()

Tags: pygame, fft, series

I am trying to code Fourier Series on PyGame. I am having a problem that I can't pass `float` values in the function:

```py
circle_x = radius * math.cos(angle)
circle_y = radius * math.sin(angle)
pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 255, 255), (circle_x, circle_y), 8, 0)
```

Comment: You might want to clarify how not being able to pass float values for `circle_x` and `circle_y` is problematic for your specific application. And as it stands, your question doesn't have anything specific to Fourier Series yet, so the `fft` and `series` tags are a little misleading.

Answer (score 1):

There are no floating-point pixel co-ordinates, they're all integers from 0 to *window_width*-1.  So there is no reason for `pygame.draw.circle()` to take floating-point arguments.  Even if you wrote your own circle-drawing function, it just moves the need to use integers from the circle-level to the pixel-level.

Probably you can just use the `round( float_value, decimal_places=0 )` function, which will round to an integer if the decimal places parameter is `0` (the default)

```py
circle_x = round( radius * math.cos(angle) )
circle_y = round( radius * math.sin(angle) )
pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 255, 255), (circle_x, circle_y), 8, 0)
```